# Django show the tags in the order in which they are added to particular test

Tags: python, django

I am relatively new to django.

I have following two models.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=70, unique=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Tag"
        verbose_name_plural = "Tags"
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag     

class Test(models.Model):
    testname = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag", null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Test"
        verbose_name_plural="Tests"
```

When I am retrieving the Test, it is giving me the tags of particular test in the order of tag id. 
My requirement is to show the tags in the order in which they are added to particular test.

**For example**, I have added a test test1 with tags, java, .net, python.
and then 2nd test test2 with tags django.
updated test2 to add tags python, java.

Now, when I am showing the test2, it shows the tags like - java, python, django.
I want it to show in the linkage order like django, python, java. [As per the tags added to particular test.]

I tried to find out in different ordering documentation, but not able get the answer.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships , you can try like this:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=70, unique=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Tag"
        verbose_name_plural = "Tags"
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag     

class Test(models.Model):
    testname = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, through='TagOrder')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Test"
        verbose_name_plural="Tests"

class TagOrder(models.Model): #added extra model for adding an additional field 'added'
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
    added = models.DateTimeField()
```

in views:

```
category= Category.objects.get(id='id')
tag= Tag.objects.get_or_create(tag='some_tag')
test= Test.objects.get_or_create(testname= 'some test', category= category )
tagorder= TagOrder.objects.create(test= test, tag= tag, added= datetime.now())

tags= TagOrder.objects.filter(test=test).order_by('added').select_related('tag')

for t in tags:
   print t.tag.tag
```

PS: Its an untested code